# One quantity for group of variations

Tags: plugins, e-commerce

I'm using WooCommerce and i want to implement a Balloon Store and according to our products' attributes, i have to define three attributes **(Size,Pack,Fill)** with different reduce quantity steps and price, but i have to define stock quantity for group of variations, for example *we have 1000ct of 11" balloon and 800ct for 9"*.

So i can't define quantity in product level and also i can't define 1000 for each variation.

I have to define 1000ct of 11" for group of variations and 800ct for 9".

This is my product table.
[image]

How can i define quantity for group of variation.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add it in product level by clicking the manage stock options for each variation in woocommerce. I guess you are using woocommerce.

Comment: If i use in product level the quantity will be for one product, but the quantity of 11" Balloon is different from 9" Balloon, so it should be in variation level.

Comment: Don't you set the product stock after creating the variation? Or you unable to find out that options?

Comment: i know where is the field of quantity for variation, my problem is how can i set one quantity for group of variation, according to table that i posted in my question.